# Issue with waiting for an event to be done then execute another

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use jQuery Promises to solve a problem.

I have a UI in which I make an API call and waiting for a response (Which takes a while). I want to wait for the response to see if everything is loaded then do an action. How can I achieve this?

This is my code:

```
                var d1 = new $.Deferred();

                if(($('.fa-spin').length + $('.chart-loading').length )==0){
                  d1.resolve();
                }   //Logic behind here is, I'm checking for loading icon, 
                    loading spinner and once they are destroyed, 
                    I want to execute something!

                    $.when(d1).then(function() {
                      console.log("fetched");
                      //Run something
                    });
```

I want to check if my loading spinner is done, and then fire an event. How can I do this?

**When I execute this code, the deferred never gets resolved and fetch is never printed**

Comment: the deferred never gets resolved because you check fo the conditon `($('.fa-spin').length + $('.chart-loading').length )==0` exactly once, immediately, and never again, so unless that condition is true just after creating the Deferred, the Deferred will never resolve

Comment: How do I keep checking then? Sorry, kinda new here!

Comment: what causes the condition to be met?

Comment: After AJAX call is done, everything is rendered, the .fa-spin and .chart-loading will be removed. Meaning their length will be 0. That's when I can consider that page rendering is done.  Then i want to execute //somelogic

Comment: can you `resolve` in the same piece of code that does the Ajax? that's about all I can suggest without seeing more code - I think there's probably a better, neater way to do all this without resorting to `$.Deferred` - but that's just a cows opinion

Comment: We will need to know more about what controls `fa-spin` and `chart-loading` because you need an event driven scheme for knowing when they are done.  Probably you want to hook directly into the ajax call completion, not into the spinner.

Comment: I'm not hooking up the AJAX call, because onSuccess() of AJAX call renders another region.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you'll need to continually check in order to resolve:

```
var d1 = new $.Deferred();

var testInterval = setInterval(function() {
  if(($('.fa-spin').length + $('.chart-loading').length )==0){
    clearInterval(testInterval);
    d1.resolve();
  }
},100);

$.when(d1).then(function() {
    console.log("fetched");
    //Run something
});
```

this will check every .1sec if the spinner's gone, and resolve your defer object when the condition is met.  although, you could just run your code there instead of as a defer/resolve.

additionally it might be more effective to hook into your actual process rather than the existence of a spinner dom object, consider implementing an existing observer pattern or roll your own: [observer pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/javascript/observer-design-pattern)